# How do I enable the visual diff tool for a Dexterity content type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've enabled versioning for a Dexterity content type I'm developing. I'm currently using Plone 4.1 and Dexterity 1.0.1.

I've added the [collective.dexteritydiff](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritydiff) package and following the instructions on the site, I've added a Compound Diff for Dexterity for my content type using the portal_diff tool in ZMI.

The Compare and Compare to Current links are now showing in the History pane for my content type items however clicking on either produces the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFEditions.browser.diff, line 61, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFDiffTool.CMFDiffTool, line 156, in createChangeSet
  Module Products.CMFDiffTool.ChangeSet, line 80, in computeDiff
  Module Products.CMFDiffTool.CMFDiffTool, line 142, in computeDiff
  Module collective.dexteritydiff.compounddiff, line 37, in __init__
  Module collective.dexteritydiff.compounddiff, line 60, in _diff
  Module collective.dexteritydiff.compounddiff, line 74, in _diff_schema
  Module collective.dexteritydiff.compounddiff, line 93, in _diff_field
  Module Products.CMFDiffTool.BaseDiff, line 26, in __init__
  Module Products.CMFDiffTool.BaseDiff, line 81, in _getValue
AttributeError: subjects
```

I've declared the class for my content type programmatically. Is there anything I need to add to my code to make the diff tool work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known bug](http://groups.google.com/group/dexterity-development/browse_thread/thread/87fa0cc682431605/369766413f09e836?show_docid=369766413f09e836) on **collective.dexteritydiff**; also, please note that release 1.0.1 of Dexterity a little bit buggy; please update to [the latest one](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.dexterity).